# No overload for method '(method)' takes 1 argument

Tags: c#, sql, overloading, datarow, private-methods

I have this quote, and it keeps showing me error:

> no overload for method `getDistinctRegister5' takes 1 argument.

```
private int getDistinctRegister5(string module, string sij)
    {
        string dateFrom = TbDateFrom.Text.Trim();
        string dateTo = TbDateTo.Text.Trim();

        string strConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SilverInfocomm"].ConnectionString;
        SqlConnection myConnect = new SqlConnection(strConnectionString);
        string sql = "SELECT COUNT( DISTINCT NRIC) FROM REGISTER WHERE Module='" + module + "' AND SIJ='" + sij + "'";

        if (dateTo != "" && dateTo != "")
        {
            sql += "AND Date>= CONVERT(DATETIME,'" + dateFrom + "',103) AND Date <= CONVERT(DATETIME,'" + dateTo + "',103)";
        }

        else if (dateFrom != "")
        {
            sql += "AND DATE= CONVERT(DATETIME,'" + dateFrom + "',103)";
        }

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, myConnect);
        myConnect.Open();
        int numrows = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
        myConnect.Close();
        return numrows;
    }


protected void GetSIJDetails()
    {
        SIJDetailsDT = new DataTable();
        SIJDetailsDT.Columns.Add("SIJ", typeof(string));
        SIJDetailsDT.Columns.Add("MODULE", typeof(string));
        SIJDetailsDT.Columns.Add("PLACES", typeof(string));
        SIJDetailsDT.Columns.Add("UNIQUE", typeof(string));
        SIJDetailsDT.Columns.Add("TOTALUNIQUE", typeof(string));
        SIJDetailsDT.Columns.Add("NON-UNIQUE", typeof(string));
        SIJDetailsDT.Columns.Add("TOTALNONUNIQUE", typeof(string));

        DataTable SIJTmp = new DataTable();
        string strConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SilverInfocomm"].ConnectionString;
        SqlConnection myConnect = new SqlConnection(strConnectionString);
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select DISTINCT SIJ, Module FROM Register", myConnect);
        myConnect.Open();
        SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        SIJTmp.Load(reader);
        reader.Close();
        myConnect.Close();

        foreach (DataRow dr in SIJTmp.Rows)
        {
            int PlacesSIJ = getPlacesSIJ(dr["SIJ"].ToString());
            int DistinctRegister4 = getDistinctRegister4(dr["SIJ"].ToString());
            int TotalRegister4 = getTotalRegister4(dr["SIJ"].ToString());
            int DistinctRegister5 = getDistinctRegister5(dr["Module"].ToString());
            int TotalRegister2 = getTotalRegister2(dr["Module"].ToString());
            SIJDetailsDT.Rows.Add(dr["SIJ"], dr["Module"], PlacesSIJ.ToString(), DistinctRegister5.ToString(), DistinctRegister4.ToString(), TotalRegister2.ToString(), TotalRegister4.ToString());
        }
    }
```

The line that is popping out the error is

```
int DistinctRegister5 = getDistinctRegister5(dr["Module"].ToString());
```

Comment: It is rather simple. Your method getDistinctRegister5 takes 2 arguments not one.

Comment: Explanation for [CS1501](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d9s6x486.aspx) error has sample. Please update your post with information what is not clear about the error.

Comment: I don't exactly know how to solve the error because my grid view is generated manually (column by column) @AlexeiLevenkov

Comment: @ClaudiaPeh what is the second argument on the function..whats it purpose..from where you can pass that value..

Comment: The 2 arguments are the string module and string sij. I want to count the total distinct beneficiaries in a certain module under a certain sij. Values are all taken from database @Sachu

Comment: @ClaudiaPeh then while calling the function you should supply both values..else the error will come..

Comment: I think I get what you mean. I've tried the method suggested below but the error still exists @Sachu

Comment: `int DistinctRegister5 = getDistinctRegister5(dr["Module"].ToString(),null);` hope this will not give any error..we are passing a null value to second argument..but wont get any result

Answer (score 0):

Your `getDistinctRegister5` method has two parameters `module` and `sij`.

You need to provide both when you call the method,

Answer (score 0):

you are calling `getDistinctRegister5` function with only one argument here.

```
  int DistinctRegister5 = getDistinctRegister5(dr["Module"].ToString());
```

But in functiond definition there is two arguments. So you should pass two arguments while calling the same.

Function definition

```
 int getDistinctRegister5(string module, string sij)
```